# how i can change wordpress post views?

Tags: html

i use a post view counter code in my website. here show like( 2 views ). i want it show like( 2 বার দেখা হয়েছে ) like bangla language . how i cant do it. i use this code .

function.php

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

single.php

```
<?php
          setPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>
```

postinfo.php

```
<?php
          echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>
```

my website http://techjagot.com

Comment: Change the `return "0 View";` and `return $count.' Views';` lines to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks but how i can change 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in banlga world like ০,১,২,৩,৪,৫,৬,৭,৮,৯ for post view code?

Comment: Try looking at http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/ and localization as the correct way to go. For the superfast, speedy, way you can try [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) if the number can be substituted as is, left-to-right. `str_replace( array( '1', '2' ... ), array( '০', '১' .. ), $count`

Comment: only this code i use in function.php str_replace( array( '1', '2' ... ), array( '০', '১' .. ), $count ?